# How to safely deallocate pointer/reference to a heap allocated array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory, memory-management

What the title says,

```
struct Foo
{
    int *arrayPointer;

    Foo (int * _arr) : arrayPointer(_arr) {}
};

int main()
{
    int *arr = new int[65536]; // edit to clarify, arr needs to be on heap, its massive
    
    Foo foo(arr);

    //do stuff

    delete [] arr; // is this correct, do i need a deconstructor?

    return 0;
}
```

My understanding is that `arrayPointer` is a normal pointer variable that gets destroyed when `foo` goes out of scope, but I want to be sure I am not risking some memory leak.

Comment: The code as written has well-defined behavior and no memory leak. But don't write code like this. Use `std::vector<int>` instead and think about whether the `Foo` object is supposed to own the array or not, i.e. whether the lifetime of the array should be bound to that of `foo`.

Comment: Why is `std::vector<int>` better to use? And what does it mean for `Foo` to own the array? thanks

Comment: In general code where resources are owned by some object on the stack are easier to write/maintain than other code, since you don't need to implement cleanup logic before every return or worry about exceptions possibly skipping the cleanup. Your code does free all resources in every possible execution path though, but simply allocating the 16 ints on the stack where they're automatically cleaned up without the need to use `delete[]` would be simpler: `int arr[16];`

Comment: `std::vector` does the memory management for you. You don't ever need to think about deleting it. With _owning_ I mean that it looks like you want the array to be created together with `Foo` object and destroyed when the `Foo` object is destroyed. So the allocation should happen in the constructor of `Foo` and the destruction in the destructor of `Foo`. With `std::vector` the destructor part isn't required. (But if you delete in the destructor instead of using `std::vector`, which you shouldn't do, read up about the rule-of-zero/three/five first.)

Comment: Also if you copy the `foo` object, would you expect the array to be copied as well? Because with your current setup that is not the case. Again `std::vector` as a member instead of the pointer will automatically do the right thing, copying all elements.

Comment: Note that gibberish like "if foo has/owns its arr?" comes from overly abstract examples that we do not face when we write our programs. If you had used real meaningful names like "game" and "board" then question "if game has/owns it board?" becomes reasonable.

Comment: I see what you mean, I definitely want `main` to own `arr`, I guess simplifying my problem like this might've made it a bit misleading, As for `std::vector`, I'll definitely try to learn it better, seems like it's actually the simpler option after all. Thanks for the answers, very helpful.

Comment: `std::vector` is better to use because it is designed to manage a dynamically allocated array/collection. Use it correctly, and all memory it dynamically allocates will exist for as long as the vector exists, and be correctly released when the vector ceases to exist. If the vector is a member of your `Foo`, then the `Foo` implicitly (no effort on your part) controls lifetime of the vector.  Your approach requires *you* to explicitly manage the memory - which typically becomes much more complicated as your codebase grows - and ensure the dynamically allocated array is cleaned up exactly once.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> delete [] arr; // is this correct
> ```

In a way, that is a correct way to deallocate a dynamic array owned by a bare pointer, but that isn't sufficient to cover all possible code paths, and using owning bare pointers should be avoided in the first place.

> I want to be sure I am not risking some memory leak.

There is a risk of memory leak: If "do something" throws, then the delete expression won't be executed.

> How to safely deallocate pointer/reference to a heap allocated array

By deallocating only within a destructor of a class that implements the RAII idiom. There is a container in the standard library that conveniently creates a dynamic array, and uses the RAII idiom: `std::vector`. I recommend using it.

Comment: So adding a try/catch clause around `//do stuff` with the delete and then switching to `std::vectors` would cover eliminate any memory leaks? Also, does `std::vector` do its stack/heap allocation automatically or is it the same as anything else (do I specifically have to use `new`)?

Comment: @jon A try-catch should be sufficient in this example, I think. You don't have to use `new` with vector. The vector allocates and deallocates within its member functions.

Answer (score 0):

In a wider view, five decades of experience suggests that it is not, in fact, possible to use the new/delete approach to managing heap-allocated arrays (and other objects) safely.

You may, just, be able to write it correctly in a 20-line exercise, and the other answers and comments give suggestions for things to check. In any real-world program, there will be memory management errors; memory leaks, use-after-free, double free and so on. Some will be security issues, others "just" availability. At best, you can manage the risk, never eliminate it; using tools like `valgrind` to check the amount of memory leaked and make sure that it's acceptable, that sort of thing.

The alternative is to switch to another approach to managing heap-allocated space; however, that would mostly mean switching to another programming language, one which uses either *garbage collection* or *borrow checking*, so that's often not a workable solution.

Comment: For C++ the alternative is RAII, and it works well.

Comment: Yes, RAII works well if you can do it perfectly. Which, as it turns out, humans can't.

Comment: It works reliably for me and I don’t think I’m better than an average c++ coder.  For most people it just means using std::vector (etc) instead of new and delete.